# Problem in decoding parameters in get method, JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, unicode, character-encoding, get

Here how jsp page is called.

```
eventMap.jsp?venue=%C4%B0ndigo
```

This is the line in eventMap.jsp which I get venue parameter:

```
var venue="<%= URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("venue"),"UTF-8") %>";
```

Unfortunately this is the result in final javascript:

```
var venue="Ä°ndigo";
```

How can I use encoding properly in jsp page in order to get decoded value correctly (İngido).

Edit:
Whole eventMap.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import = "java.net.URLDecoder"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Event on Map></title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
  function initialize() {
    <% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %> 
    var lat=<%= request.getParameter("lat") %>;
    var lng=<%= request.getParameter("lng") %>;
    var venue="<%= URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("venue"),"UTF-8") %>";

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng, 
        map: map,
        title:"Hello"
    });   

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: venue, size: new google.maps.Size(50,50)});
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Firebug Result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
2
3
4<html>
5<head>
6<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
7<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
8<title>Event on Map</title>
9<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
10<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
11<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
12 function initialize() {
13 var lat=41.062786;
14 var lng=28.981934;
15 var venue="Ä°TÃ KÃ¼ltÃ¼r Sanat BirliÄi (KSB) BinasÄ± KÃ¼Ã§Ã¼k Salon (Maslak)";
16
17 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
18 var myOptions = {
19 zoom: 15,
20 center: myLatlng,
21 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
22 }
23 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
24
25 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
26 position: myLatlng,
27 map: map,
28 title:"Hello"
29 });
30
31 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: venue, size: new google.maps.Size(50,50)});
32 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
33 infowindow.open(map,marker);
34 });
35
36 }
37</script>
38</head>
39<body onload="initialize()">
40 <div id="map_canvas"></div>
41</body>
42
43</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decoding of the GET query string is handled by the servletcontainer, not by the Servlet API. It's unclear which servletcontainer you're using, so I can't give a detailed answer. In for example Tomcat, it's [configureable](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) by `URIEncoding` attribute in the `<Connector>` element in `/conf/server.xml`.

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8">
```

Configuration is similar in other servletcontainers.

Then you can remove the unnecessary `URLDecoder` line. The `getParameter()` already returns the decoded parameter.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) - [JSP/Servlet request](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletRequest)

---

Unrelated to the actual problem, I strongly recommend to replace *scriptlets* by EL and use JSTL `fn:escapeXml` to prevent XSS attacks.

```
var lat = ${fn:escapeXml(param.lat)};
var lng = ${fn:escapeXml(param.lng)};
var venue = "${fn:escapeXml(param.venue)}";
```

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: Yep, now it works, but what if I don't have access to server config files?

Comment: Ensure that you pick/choose a decent hosting with good support and inform whether it's set to UTF-8. Otherwise you've to hack around it with manually parsing `request.getQueryString()` with help of a `Filter` and `HttpServletRequestWrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

What does your JSP header look like?

Make sure it says something like:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xhtml;charset=UTF-8"%>
```

You can also check HTTP headers you are getting when invoking your JSP. Make sure your response is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Have you tried FIREBUG to access your JSP? What does the **encoding** looks like?

Comment: The key is the `pageEncoding` attribute, not the `contentType` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this method is overriding the wrong encoding:
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")

Probably you should check the encoding to be used in your JSP header or in the request header.

Charlie

Comment: This only applies on POST query string in request body, not on GET query string in request URL.