# unicode character not showing when reciving value from request in a jsp page

Tags: jsp, unicode

I am facing some problem to show unicode characters in a jsp.

I have done as following

```
String s1="\u0985";
String s2=request.getParameter("str");

out.println("s1:=="+s1);
out.println("s2:=="+s2);
```

now when we are passing the same value `(\u0985)` as `s1` to the `s2`.

output:

```
s1:==অ
s2:==\u0985
```

i want `s1` and `s2` give me the same output.
Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Couldnt get you . can you post the expected output?

Comment: I am passing \u0985 to the str by url. so s2 is getting \u0985. now s1 and s2 have the same value. so why the output are different. I want s1:==অ
s2:==অ

Comment: But you need `s2` to display like this `অ` . correct?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are passing `str`?

Comment: url is localhost:8080/testUnicode/displayUni.jsp?str=\u0985

Comment: Try this `String s2 = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("str"), 'UTF-8');` in your jsp

Comment: You need to encode the URI as you are passing in the query string . see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225206/problem-in-decoding-parameters-in-get-method-jsp) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469874/how-do-i-correctly-decode-unicode-parameters-passed-to-a-servlet) examples. And also [read this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)